# Monitoring calls even if the app gets killed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uibackgroundmode

I have to monitore the calls in background even when the app gets killed and send a local notification. Is that any way to keep do such thing like that? I mean beyond the 10 minutes too. So far, I can monitoring the calls and send the notification but only without killed the app. Thanks in advanced.

Here's how I'm doing:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;

    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];

    [self startMonitoringCalls];
}

-(void)startMonitoringCalls
{

    callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

    [callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call) {
        if ([[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateConnected]) {
            NSLog(@"Get called");
        } else if ([[call callState] isEqual:CTCallStateDisconnected]) {

            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
            notification.alertBody = @"Would you like to...";
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: When an app is killed its not running. When an app is not running how can it possibly do anything? If you don't actually mean killed then get your terminology correct and describe exactly what you mean. If you don't mean killed, do you mean suspended while in the background?

Comment: I believe that the short answer to your question is "No".  iOS has some background execution modes, but your case doesn't meet any of those.

Comment: The foursquare for example, knows where you are even if you tap the home twice and kill the app. That is what I wanted but turned to call's monitoring.

Comment: Foursquare is using the location background mode, which under some  circumstances will relaunch the app if its been killed. However there is no equivalent for monitoring phone calls. The best you could hope for is to have a *legitimate* use for being able to use one of the background modes that would enable you to run your call monitoring code and re-launch your app when killed. If you don't have a legitimate use your app would be rejected from the app store.

Comment: @MartinH, you answer my answer. I think the best way is you put an answer for I flag you as correct and close the question, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foursquare is using the location background mode, which under some circumstances will relaunch the app if its been killed. However there is no equivalent for monitoring phone calls. The best you could hope for is to have a legitimate use for being able to use one of the background modes that would enable you to run your call monitoring code and re-launch your app when killed. If you don't have a legitimate use your app would be rejected from the app store.